# C++ - Merging two sorted vectors of different, unique types with a common attribute into a new sorted vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, merge, std

There are two types, A and B. These types both have a common attribute, a key.

There are two vectors of type A and B. These vectors are sorted by key ascending. The vectors are unique in regards to their keys - ie if a key is present in A_vect it is guaranteed to not be present in B_vect and vice versa.

The goal is to take the keys in vector A_vect, construct new B types and put them into B_vect, such that B contains it's original keys and it's new keys. The new B_vect should also be sorted.

I have this code snippet so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


struct A
{
    A(int i)
    {
        key = i;
    }
    
    int key;
};

struct B
{
    B(int i)
    {
        key = i;
    }
    
    B()
    {
    }
    
    int key;
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<A> a_diff_sorted_vect = {1, 3};
    std::vector<B> b_sorted_vect = {2, 4};

    std::transform
    (
        a_diff_sorted_vect.begin(), a_diff_sorted_vect.end(), 
        std::back_inserter(b_sorted_vect), 
        [](const A &a) -> B
        {
            B b;
            b.key   = a.key;
            
            return b;
        }
     );
     
    std::cout << "Printing b_sorted_vect" << "\n";
    for(auto element : b_sorted_vect)
    {
        std::cout << std::to_string(element.key) << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Finished printing b_sorted_vect" << "\n";
    
    /*
        std::sort
        (
            b_sorted_vect.begin(), 
            b_sorted_vect.end(), 
            [](B lhs, B rhs) 
            {
                return lhs.key < rhs.key;
            }
        );
        
        std::cout << "Printing b_sorted_vect" << "\n";
        for(auto element : b_sorted_vect)
        {
            std::cout << std::to_string(element.key) << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "Finished printing b_sorted_vect" << "\n";
    */

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 2
> 4
> 1
> 3

Desired output:

> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4

Ideally I would like to avoid the top-down std::sort at the end, as I think there might be a more efficient way to do that during construction and merging. The std::sort is my current solution.

The use of a third temporary vector might be necessary, which is fine.

This should be done with C++11, using boost if necessary.

Comment: `std::set_union` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_union

Comment: Since you know the amount of elements you are going to insert, you should start by reserving space in `vect_b`.  Then benchmark different approaches. What's best probably depends quite a bit on the size of the vectors.

Comment: @macroland the vectors are of different types. Is it possible to use set_union with two arbitrary types, and if so, how?